# how to extract a unicode string with boost.python

Tags: python, boost, unicode, boost-python

It seems that the code will crash when I do `extract<const char*>("a unicode string")`

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Don't have a definitive answer, but [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-July/014720.html) and [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-July/014664.html) I found some references that might be of interest to you

Comment: Is this the error you are getting? "TypeError: No registered converter was able to extract a C++ pointer to type char from this Python object of type unicode." Could you give example code and/or give a idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It is really not clear. What is the argument you give to extract? Is it a literal string? A boost::python::object?

Comment: You are supposed to accept the correct answer to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles and works for me, **with your example string** and using Python 2.x:

```
void process_unicode(boost::python::object u) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  const char* value = extract<const char*>(str(u).encode("utf-8"));
  std::cout << "The string value is '"<< value << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

You can write [a specific from-python converter](http://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/how-to-write-boost-python-converters/), if you wish to auto-convert `PyUnicode` (@Python2.x) to `const wchar_t*` or to a type from [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings) (that seems to be the common recommendation for dealing with Unicode on C++).

If you want full support to unicode characters which are not in the ASCII range (for example, accented characters such as `á`, `ç` or `ï`, you *will need* to write the from-python converter. Note this will have to be done separately for Python 2.x and 3.x, if you wish to support both. For Python 3.x, the [PyUnicode type was deprecated](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html) and now the string type works as `PyUnicode` used to for Python 2.x. <strike>Nothing that a couple of `#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000` cannot handle</strike>.

**[edit]**

The above comment was wrong. Note that, since Python 3.x treats unicode strings as normal strings, `boost::python` will wrap that into `boost::python::str` objects. I have not verified how those are handled w.r.t. unicode translation in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
extract<std::string>("a unicode string").c_str()
```

or

```
extract<wchar_t*>(...)
```